# I need a button to change currency using vue.js

Tags: vue.js

this is my first time asking here, so apologize my mistakes.

Using vue I get a Json

`[ { } "price_usd": 110000, "price_uyu": 4786100, } ]`

and i have this:

```
 <div class="col-5">
  <span id="valueUSD"> USD {{car_actual.price_usd}} </span>
 </div>
```

and when i click a button i need to change this:

```
<span id="valorUSD"> USD {{car_actual.price_usd}} </span>
```

for this:

```
<span id="valueUYU"> UYU {{car_actual.price_uyu}} </span>
```

and if I click again i need to change back.

Tell me if you need further information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably how I would go about it

```html
<template>
  <button v-for="currency in supportedCurrencies" :key="currency" :click="selectCurrency(currency)">{{ currency }}</button>
  <span v-for="car in carData" :id=`valor${selectedCurrency}`> {{ selectedCurrency }} {{ getCarPrice(car) }} </span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      carData: [
        { "price_usd": 110000, "price_uyu": 4786100 }, // each object is a car
        ...
      ],
      selectedCurrency: 'USD',
      supportedCurrencies: ['USD', 'UYU']
    }
  },
  methods: {
    selectCurrency (currency) {
      this.selectedCurrency = currency
    },
    getCarPrice (car) {
      switch (this.selectedCurrency) {
        case 'USD':
          return car.price_usd
        case 'UYU':
          return car.price_uyu
        default:
          return 'No Pricing Available in ' + this.selectedCurrency
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

One thing to note is that you could probably improve `getCarPrice` to scale with `supportedCurrencies` in a way that doesn't require you to have to update two different parts of the code when a new currency is added.

Also, `selectedCurrency` is hardcoded, so if you plan on having dynamic defaults (maybe each user sees it in their own currency), then considering moving everything into a child component and passing in the default currency as a prop after retrieving it from the server.

Other than that, if you only plan on supporting two currencies, this should probably suffice.